# If I move an encrypted file from NTFS to HFS will the encryption be removed?

Tags: encryption, ntfs, hfs+

Trying to move encrypted files from one File System to another, assume equal credentials. I understand that since FS such as FAT do not support encryption the encryption would be dropped upon file move, but what about a FS that supports encryption?

Comment: On what operating system?

Answer (score 0):

The file will be decrypted when it is read from the old filesystem. Whether or not it will be encrypted when it is written to the new filesystem depends on the new filesystem's settings.